# Rendition or Rendering?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, music

What is a better choice between the words {1} Rendition and {2} Rendering?
For a reviewer of a piece of drama or music, which word is appropriate?

If we want to consider parts of speech:

1. [Rendition](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/rendition?q=Rendition) NOUN **the performance or version of a piece of music or drama; The particular way in which it is performed.**
2. [Rendering](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/rendering?q=rendering)  NOUN **the performance of a piece of music, a role in a play etc; the particular way in which something  is performed.** SYNONYM INTERPRETATION,rendition: Her dramatic rendering of Lady
   Macbeth.

Both seem to be of the same meaning and same part of speech (from New Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary).

Comment: "Interpretation" is more common for the uses you refer to. Although you can use "rendition" for an individual performance of a single song, it's unlikely that you'd use either "rendering" or "rendition" in a review in any other way. You might technically be able to use "rendering" for the score or script when someone rewrites someone else's work, but save that for a sarcastic bad review.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely *rendition*.  I defy anyone with experience in the kitchen to hear "rendering" and not picture the cellist simultaneously bowing and [heating chicken fat over a low fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_(animal_products)).

Comment: I defy anyone with experience in graphics processing to hear "rendering" and not picture "picture making"! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- I myself have a lot more experience with graphics processing than with making [schmaltz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schmaltz), but the latter is lot funnier to imagine someone doing the latter on stage.

Comment: I have a good chunk of education and professional experience with both types of rendering! From a long-running side gig as a nightclub bouncer, I also associate it with the local emergency responders saying “[…] rendering/rendered them unconscious” over the radio. (Nothing I did! I was never that careless, vindictive, or unlucky.) I'm not sure if the verbal uniformity is a cultural artifact or deliberate protocol for accuracy/cognitive load reduction/etc. I’d guess a bit of both. Anecdote aside, I was unsure enough about the distinction to google it while writing some interface blurbs.

Comment: (To be clear, I'm working on software that renders webpages. It will not extract liquid fat from solid fat, and certainly won't knock someone out.)